# Application folder is empty

Tags: snow-leopard

I am using OSX - Snow Leopard on my Mac.
I could find the Application folder is empty, please help.
Thank you!

Regards,
Krishna

Comment: In Finder, please type Cmd-Shift-G, enter "/Applications" (without the "") in the dialog and press enter. Is the newly opened window still empty? If yes, open Terminal.app, type `ls -l /Applications` followed by Enter. Is there any result?

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking at Home/Applications instead of /Applications

Answer (score 7):

As stated by Tom. you may be looking in the wrong Applications folder.  There are 2 - the main one is in the root directory so all users can access them: There are various ways to see root - I use shift-command-c  from a finder window - you should see all your drives/network/servers etc.  Click on main OS drive, probably called Macintosh HD and the main App folder will be there. You will also see the Users folder.  If you delve into there, you may well see another, possibly empty Application folder.  This is for Apps to be used by that user only.